# repartir elementor a lo largo de un linear layout horizontal

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un linear layout horizontal de esta forma:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxComida"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Comida"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonComida"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Elegir hora" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horaComida"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="left|center"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

y queria que los tres elementor (checkbox,button y textview) se distribuyesen equilibradamente a lo largo del linear layout. He probado ya varias cosas y ninguna funciono.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Usa `android:layout_weight="1"` , de esta forma se distribuiran equitativamente en tu layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxComida"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Comida"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonComida"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Elegir hora" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horaComida"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no me ha funcionado.

Comment: que raro, puedes agregar una imagen de como se muestra y como deseas se muestren?